# Ionic 3 : How can i get variable inside observable

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

As I remark at title How can I get variable inside observable?

```
temp$ : Observable<any[]>;
onChange(changedValue){
        this.temp$ = this.database.list('Libraries/').valueChanges();       
            this.temp$.subscribe((data) =>{
                console.log(data);
            }); 
         }
```

This function helps me for getting data through a database push data into an Observable called temp$.

I can see what's inside of temp$ from the console of Google Chrome and it's totally true but I can not reach nameOfCity variable..

```
0: {nameOfCity: " esk", nameOfLibrary: "yaa"}
1: {nameOfCity: " esk", nameOfLibrary: "baskabir"}
2: {nameOfCity: " Tokat", nameOfLibrary: "dasdas"}
3: {nameOfCity: " Sivas", nameOfLibrary: "asdasd"}
4: {nameOfCity: " Sivas", nameOfLibrary: "bsad"}
5: {nameOfCity: " esk", nameOfLibrary: "dsad"}
6: {nameOfCity: " Tokat", nameOfLibrary: "dd"}
.
.
.
```

**How can i get nameOfCity from temp$ variable like** `temp.nameOfCity`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it clear in the first place, it's not `temp$` that contains the data you're looking for, the variable `data` from your arrow function is the one that does. Since you have to subscribe to an Observable in order to get the data you're looking for, the snippet below should guide you in the right way.

```
onChange(changedValue) {

    this.database.list('Libraries/').valueChanges()
        .subscribe((data) => {

            // data seems to be an array of object from your example
            // Having this in mind, you can iterate over the array and
            // cityInfos will be used to identify the objects

            for (let cityInfos of data) {
                console.log(cityInfos);
                console.log(cityInfos.nameOfCity);
                console.log(cityInfos.nameOfLibrary);
            }

        });

}
```

Extending this, you should be able to redeclare a variable accessible in the scope of the arrow function and more specifically, where the 3 `console.log` are.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like temp$ is an array. So if you want to access nameOfCity you should access first an element of the array like this:
`temp$[0].nameOfCity`.

Please let me know if this helps or if I got something wrong.

Comment: It worked , Thanks! And then should I use for loop or foreach ? How can i use them? Sorry for these question. I don't know well that platform and javascript as well.

Comment: No problem. Yo can either use a for loop or any method javascript already has. Yo can look for it here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp
I think foreach would be apropriate.